# zip does not work for imshow: TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, imshow

I saw similar questions elsewhere, but they came from different codes. My case is to transpose the data with `zip`, then use the `imshow`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
img_data=zip(*a)
plt.imshow(img_data)
```

I got 
    TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` returns an iterator object (in python3, and not a container such as a list/array). What you'd want to do is convert the `zip` object to a format that `imshow` understands. There are a couple of options.

**Option 1**
Convert to a `list` -

```
img_data = list(zip(*a))
plt.imshow(img_data)
```

---

**Option 2**
Convert `a` to a numpy array and transpose. Since you're using `zip` to the same effect, this makes sense.

```
plt.imshow(np.array(a).T)
```

---

[image]